# How do I change the output of burst time

Tags: java

The code displays `0` instead of every 3rd input in the given values. What should I do in order to print out the `5 3 8 6` in the input?

The output should be like this (burst time reference only):
[image: burst time reference only]

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PreemptivePriorityScheduling {
    static int[] processId, arrivalTime, burstTime, priority, waitingTime, turnAroundTime;
    static int n;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of processes: ");
        n = input.nextInt();
        processId = new int[n];
        arrivalTime = new int[n];
        burstTime = new int[n];
        priority = new int[n];
        waitingTime = new int[n];
        turnAroundTime = new int[n];

        getInput(input);
        computeWaitingTime();
        computeTurnAroundTime();
        displayTable();
        displayAverages();
    }

    public static void getInput(Scanner input) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter process ID, arrival time, burst time, and priority for process " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            processId[i] = input.nextInt();
            arrivalTime[i] = input.nextInt();
            burstTime[i] = input.nextInt();
            priority[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public static void computeWaitingTime() {
        int complete = 0, minPriority, minIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            minPriority = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (arrivalTime[j] <= complete && priority[j] < minPriority && burstTime[j] > 0) {
                    minPriority = priority[j];
                    minIndex = j;
                }
            }
            complete += burstTime[minIndex];
            waitingTime[minIndex] = complete - arrivalTime[minIndex] - burstTime[minIndex];
            burstTime[minIndex] = 0;
        }
    }

    public static void computeTurnAroundTime() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            turnAroundTime[i] = waitingTime[i] + burstTime[i];
        }
    }

    public static void displayTable() {
        System.out.println("Process ID\tArrival Time\tBurst Time\tPriority\tWaiting Time\tTurn Around Time");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(processId[i] + "\t\t" + arrivalTime[i] + "\t\t" + burstTime[i] + "\t\t" + priority[i] + "\t\t" + waitingTime[i] + "\t\t" + turnAroundTime[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void displayAverages() {
        int totalWaitingTime = 0, totalTurnAroundTime = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            totalWaitingTime += waitingTime[i];
            totalTurnAroundTime += turnAroundTime[i];
        }
        System.out.println("\nAverage Waiting Time: " + (float)totalWaitingTime / n);
        System.out.println("Average Turn Around Time: " + (float)totalTurnAroundTime / n);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to explain the domain and what the numbers mean. For a greater chance that someone will feel they are ready to look through your code and try to understand it.

Comment: in the method `computeWaitingTime()` you assign the value 0 for each element of the `burstTime` array - so you will always have 0 in the output.
For faster error detection, I would recommend initializing the arrays in the code, e.g.: `static int n = 4;` and `processId = new int[]{1, 0, 5, 1};`, so you don't have to use the scanner every time.

Comment: Why does your `computeWaitingTime()` manipulate the value of `burstTime[minIndex]` ?

Comment: @Mio Correct. I don’t know why you deleted your answer. I think you can undelete it. (Waiting times look funny after applying your change, but that may considered a separate problem.)